# C prog. Pointers and strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
char str[] = "hello World!!!!!";
char *ptr = str + 6;
printf("%s",ptr);
```

output: lo World!!!!!

Here in the `printf` statement it is specified `ptr` and not `*ptr` so for printing the values of variables we use `*`(dereferencing operator) with the pointer name. like for example:

```
int i=2;
int *ptr;
ptr=&i;
printf("%d",ptr);
```

which prints the address,as ptr stores the address(`&i`) similarly in top example given it should print the address and not value of `str[]` as only `ptr` is used and not `*ptr`, but it doesn't.  Why?

Comment: The "%s" printf token looks for a (char*).  In the second, you are printing a pointer as an int.  It should give you a compiler warning if you are using -Wall flag.

Comment: maybe because i didn't use the %u in place of %d,but gcc is showing correct output for the second example: 6422312 as it prints the address

Comment: If you want to become a good programmer, you should worry more about style. First of all there is consistency, you don't use white spaces consistently. Second of all, adding white spaces around operators like your first example makes the code much easier to read. Also, a space after a coma is good for the same reason.

Comment: Why? Because of the *format specifier* you used. the `%s` format requires a pointer, the `%d` format requires an `int`, and the two types are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you **MUST** pass a `char` pointer for the `"%s"` modifier so it is actually the way it has to be, you would of course know that if you read the appropriate documentation, like e.g. The C Standard.

The second one, is wrong. Because it would invoke *undefined behavior*. To print the address of a variable you need to create a pointer to it with the `&` address of operator, or directly use the address of operator and the `"%p"` `printf()` specifier, any other specifier would cause *undefined behavior*.

Using the correct specifier, would work in your first example too.

Comment: ..thanks buddy .. if i use printf("%c",*ptr); it correctly prints W but why in the first example ptr is not printing the address as we haven't used * with ptr

Comment: Thanks now by using %p it's working

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass address to a %s. The address has to be of a character from where the string will be printed from. It will print till it hits '\0' character which is the end of the string.

In the second example, %d expects a number. We can pass a address to it or the value in the address is up to us.